# Using regex in react router Route path prop

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-router

I am working on routing my pages to 404 by using regex instead of a string in [react-router path prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string)

What I have is a list of different routes in the following format:

example defintions

#### route1

```
const withdrawRuote = 'user/:userId/withdraw'
const depositRoute = 'user/:userId/deposit'
```

#### route2

```
const groupNewRoute = 'group/new'
const groupWithdrawRoute = 'group/withdraw'
const groupDepositRoute = 'group/deposit'
```

#### react-router route path regex

For Route1

```
Route(exact path=myRegex1 render=404)
```

here is [myRegex1](https://regex101.com/r/2JjwPA/44)

With the above regex, the following should PASS:

- /user/123/withdrawaaaaa
- /user/123/depositaaaaaa

should FAIL

- /user/123/withdraw
- /user/123/deposit/
- /user/123/withdraw
- /user/123/deposit/
- /user
- /user/

For Route2

```
Route(exact path=myRegex2 render=404)
```

Here is [myRegex2](https://regex101.com/r/kR0uMc/1).
These should PASS:

- /group/not/found
- /group/not

should FAIL

- /group/
- /group
- /group/deposit
- /group/withdraw

I know I can handle 404s using the switch statement but I need to know why this does not work.

How do I make regex know that i need the words `deposit` & `withdraw` or `user` as a word and not just a set of characters considering I am excluding them rather than include.

Comment: It's not clear what you have and what you expect. Please write some examples and counterexamples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the regex engine that you want to only avoid matching URLs with `withdraw` and `deposit` at the end:

```
^\/user\/?[0-9]+\/(?!(?:deposit|withdraw)\/?$).*$
                                         ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0xDR8h/1)

The `(?!(?:deposit|withdraw)\/?$)` negative lookahead will fails the match once it matches (immediately to the right of the current location):

- `(?:deposit|withdraw)` - either of the two values, `deposit` or `withdraw`
- `\/?` - one or zero (optional) `/` chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention /user/ or /user should not match.I've updated the question

Comment: @fatahn But [my regex above does not match `/user` nor `/user/`](https://regex101.com/r/0xDR8h/2). Please explain what `^\/user\/?[0-9]+` should match. Right now, it matches `/user`, `/user22343` or `/user/12234` like strings.

Comment: Thanks alot @wiktor-stribiżew, this will do for now,

Comment: It does not PASS for `/user/not/found`

Comment: @fatahn That is because of `\/?\d+`. I asked you for clarifications because you did not explain the rules. If you want to do it once and well, provide exact specs. To match `/user/not/found` make the `\/?\d+` optional, use [`^\/user(?=(\/[0-9]+)?)\1\/(?!(?:deposit|withdraw)\/?$).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/0xDR8h/3)

Comment: just updated the question with more specs, in my regex of Router2, there is are no digits but I still cant get `/accounts/` to Fail

Comment: @fatahn Replace the last `*` with `+` to require at least  1 char after `/group/`, `^\/group\/(?!(?:deposit|withdraw)\/?$).+$`, see [demo link](https://regex101.com/r/kR0uMc/2).